# Sorting alphabetically

Tags: c++

Here is my code...What would be the best way to sort names alphabetically?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int StudentNum;

    cout << "How many student are in the class?\n";
    cin >> StudentNum;

    string sname[25];
    if (StudentNum < 1 || StudentNum > 25)
    {
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1-25 and try again\n"; 
    return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= StudentNum; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Please enter the name of student #" << i << endl;
        cin >> sname[i];        
    }   
    for (int output = 0; output <=StudentNum; output++)
    {
    cout << sname[output] << endl;
    } 
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C++ are numbered from `0` to `N-1`. Your first `for` should say: `for( int i = 0; i < StudentNum; i++ )` and your second should have `output < StudentNum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way is to use `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std::sort(sname, sname + StudentNum);
```

`std::sort` uses `operator<` by default, which actually does an alphabetical comparison for strings.

EDIT: Indeed, it should be `StudentNum` instead of 25.

Comment: that should be `sname + StudentNum`

Comment: I do that and my arrays wont appear in the output.